# Strcat in assembly

Tags: assembly, strcat, att

I'm trying to concatenate two strings in Assembly but I can't seem to get it working. I have the following piece of code:

```
.data

message: .asciz "message"
leading: .asciz "leading"

.globl main

main:
    push $message
    push $leading

    call strcat

    push %eax

    call printf
...
```

When I try to append a string with more than 16 characters to another string, it gives a segmentation fault in the strcat call according to gdb. Am I missing something here? Is there any way to make strcat working on strings longer than 16 characters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated more than a total 16 bytes. You need to reserve enough memory for the resulting string to fit in the destination.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Could you please explain how to do that with strings? I'm kinda new in assembly ;)

Comment: Nevermind, I've found it. I have to use a buffer, copy message to that buffer by using strcpy and then I can append safely :)